# Cant save changes in Elementor, Document already in save progress

Tags: wordpress, performance, elementor

when trying to save changes, update button stays green and changes are not saved. I’ve tried every single advice I could found (cache cleaning, disabling plugins, enabling healt-check plugin). The error ‘Document already in save progress’ apeears in browser console. This issue can be reproduced only on one page (the biggest one). Also, on different hosting everything works fine.

This are the only plugins I use, and the theme is “OceanWP”:

[image: This are the only plugins I use, and the theme is “OceanWP”.]

The error in browser console:

[image: The error in browser console]

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:
Edit wp-config.php and insert the following lines:

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true);
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);
define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false );
```

and check the debug log at /wp-content/debug.log afterwards.

Also try to enable the Elementor Debugger to see if there are some more detailed erros:
https://elementor.com/help/elementor-debugger/

Answer (score 0):

I had a same problem and finally found the solution here :
[update button not work](https://elementor.com/help/publish-update-button-not-work/)

Comment: for an update : in my case the issue solved by deleting the last section that I was creating in elementor

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33534115)

Answer (score -1):

I was having the same issue, also I was getting an 524 error sometimes on the site, always on my browser console, for me it was related to reaching the resources limit on my hosting... Had to change to a hosting with bigger limits... I tested this by migrating my site from my current hosting to a local instance, everything worked just fine.